# What is Share Consolidation?

Tags: financial-literacy, shares

```
Subject Share Consolidation
Type    Consolidation
Description CONSOLIDATION OF EVERY 4 ORDINARY SHARES IN PDZ HOLDINGS BHD ("PDZ" OR THE "COMPANY") ("PDZ SHARES" OR "SHARES") HELD AT 5.00 P.M. ON 4 DECEMBER 2017 ("ENTITLEMENT DATE") INTO 1 PDZ SHARE ("CONSOLIDATED SHARE") ("SHARE CONSOLIDATION")
Amount  4 : 1
```

What is Share Consolidation?

If a share price is $2, I buy it with $5000.

> $5000/$2 = 2500units

Share consolidation will make the share units above decrease?

> 2500units /4 = 625units

Comment: Yes the units will be reduced. Related question https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/52205/in-a-reverse-split-what-happens-to-odd-lots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a *Reverse Stock Split*; the count will be reduced, and the price will go up accordingly.

It is like changing four 5$-bills into on one 20$-bill - now you have only one bill instead of four, but it is worth four times as much.

Nothing to worry about, this is a purely cosmetic change.